# Programmatically change Event Viewer properties in C#

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, event-viewer

IIS 7.5 supports IIS configuration change auditing by changing setting from `Event Viewer/Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Operational/Enable` Log.

I tried it through Event Viewer and it worked great.
But what I need is not to do that manually using Event Viewer.

Instead, I need to achieve that programmatically in C# through API - an API for programming the above Event Viewer property (not IIS property) so that I can enable the logging .

Is that possible?

If so, how?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a CommandLine approach is usable even from C#

Comment: That's a good work-around if no API available for Event Viewer. But, again, is there a command available for that?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I saw domething

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing !
I've just figure it out, it's quite simple:

```
string logName = "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational";
EventLogConfiguration log = new EventLogConfiguration(logName);

log.IsEnabled = true;

try
{
    log.SaveChanges();
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need administrator privileges. " + e.Message);
}
```